# Program runs forever without giving an error when plotting data only on continent

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I was trying to plot data only on continent. I asked a question about this before and I've got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13796829/1819734).
Now when I implemented it in the code, the program will run without giving an error.

However, it RUNS FOREVER. When I use `ctrl + C` to force stop it, it traces back to `"if not (map.is_land(X[i], Y[i])):"`, so I think there's something wrong here. But I can't figure it out.

Here is the part of code that involves picking out non-continental data and removing them:

```
X, Y = map(Lon,Lat)
ocean = []
for i in range(len(X)):
    if not (map.is_land(X[i], Y[i])):
        ocean.append(i)

X_new = np.delete(X, ocean)
Y_new = np.delete(Y, ocean)
HDO_new = np.delete(HDO, ocean)
```

Comment: how much memory is your program using?  If you have fallen over to swap, things can get _really_ slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a `for` loop, the program should stop anyway, the only problem is how large is `X`. I can only give two suggestions:

1) try to print the value of `len(X)` before entering the for cicle to see how big is

2) try to use `xrange` instead of `range`, if you use python 2.x

Keep also in mind that using list with some hundred thousand element seems to be slow. 
Eventually try using a smaller data sample, if you can

Comment: Yes it is very large. It has nearly 700 thousand entries. Thanks.