# Need to detect map's land/ocean points with higher accuracy than maskoceans(grid=1.25,resolution='f')

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have a grid of points on the map and I want to detect which point is in land or ocean. I have tried to do this in 3 ways but non are satisfactory.

1. Using `maskoceans`, a simple example is:

   ```
   from mpl_toolkits.basemap import maskoceans
   import numpy
   # my grid is given by lons and lats 1D arrays.
   Array = numpy.ma.zeros((lats.size,lons,size))
   Lons,Lats = numpy.meshgrid(lons,lats)
   MaskedArray = maskoceans(Lons,Lats,Array,resolution='f',grid=1.25)
   ```

Now I have `MaskedArray` where locations on ocean are masked. This method is *really* fast compared to others, but *inaccurate* near the coast for small scales. In the following plot, red dots are identified as land, black points are identified as ocean. As you see even if I have used the `resolution='f'` (the full reslution) and smallest masked grid (`grid=1.25`) there are erounous points in ocean that are marked as land in red. It seems that the `f` resolution of `maskoceans` is not in the same order of the `f` resolution of `Basemap`.

[Image of points detected with maskoceans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmV5S.png)

2. Use `basemap.is_land()`. Example is:

   ```
   # Create a basemap object, this takes a while!
   MinLat = numpy.min(lats) - 0.01
   MinLon = numpy.min(lons) - 0.01
   MaxLat = numpy.max(lats) + 0.01
   MaxLon = numpy.max(lons) + 0.01
   MidLat = numpy.mean(lats)
   MidLon = numpy.mean(lons)
   from mpl_tookits.basemap import Basemap
   map = Basemap(projection='aeqd',llcrnrlat=MinLat,llcrnrlon=MinLon,urcrnrlat=MaxLat,urcrnrlon=MaxLon,area_thresh=0.01,lon_0=MidLon,lat_0=MidLat,resolution='f')
   Array = numpy.zeros((lats.size,lons.size),dtype=bool)
   for j in range(lats.size):
       for i in range(lons.size):
           x,y = map(lon[i],lat[j])
           if map.is_land(x,y):
               Array[j,i] = True
   ```

This is the most accurate method. As you see in the figure below, all points are detected correctly. The big issue with `is_land()` is that it is *very slow*. For large grids this method takes minutes (in order of an hour for very large grids), which `maskoceans` take less than a second.

[Image of points detected with Basemap.is_land](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T63Z2.png)

3. Using `Polygon.contains_point`. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13811775/1764258). This does not work for me, since the polygons of the coastlines should be *closed* in order to use `conians_point`. Hence the `map` object should be defined on the the full globe with

   ```
    map = Basemap(projection='aeqd',lon_0=0,resolution='f')
   ```

If the map is defined on a window of lon and lat, the coastline polygon is not closed. But the loading the full map with the full resolution takes a very long time and memory, and detecting even one point takes forever.

Is there an alternative method to identify land/ocean points on a given grid? It would prefer to use `maskoceans` if the resolution issue is fixed. It is possible to increase the resolution of `maskoceans()` up to the resolution of `Basemap`?

Comment: The polygons in a windowed basemap are closed and `contains_points()` works as expected.