# Fill oceans in basemap (don't plot colour grid on oceans)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, colors, matplotlib-basemap

My question is the same as this one: [Fill oceans in basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620803/fill-oceans-in-basemap). I know there is an answer given here, but when I try to apply the answer to my code, it doesn't work.

Here is my original graph.

[image: Original plot]

I want to make the oceans white and only show the colour differences on Antarctica.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Path, PathPatch

D = pd.read_pickle('directory')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

lons = D['longitude'][:]
lats = D['latitude'][:]
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
variable_to_graph = D['variable_to_graph']

m = Basemap(projection='spstere', boundinglat=-60, lon_0=180, resolution='l')
m.drawcoastlines(color='k') # shows Antarctica

x,y = m(lon, lat)
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, variable_to_graph, cmap='viridis', vmin=-400, vmax=-0)

# Getting the limits of the map:
x0,x1 = ax.get_xlim()
y0,y1 = ax.get_ylim()
map_edges = np.array([[x0,y0], [x1,y0], [x1,y1], [x0,y1]])

# Getting all polygons used to draw the coastlines of the map
polys = [p.boundary for p in m.landpolygons]

# Combining with map edges.
polys = [map_edges]+polys[:]

# Creating a PathPatch.
codes = [
    [Path.MOVETO] + [Path.LINETO for p in p[1:]]
    for p in polys
]

polys_lin = [v for p in polys for v in p]
codes_lin = [c for cs in codes for c in cs]
path = Path(polys_lin, codes_lin)
patch = PathPatch(path,facecolor='white', lw=0)

# Masking the data:
ax.add_patch(patch)

plt.show()
```

Which gives me this.

[image: Result]

I have also tried using a is_land() function but as the resolution is relatively low (1x1 degrees) the image is not very neat.

[image: Fill result]

Any help would be appreciated as to how to get the colour map to only show on Antarctica and for it to stop on the edges of Antarctica.

EDIT: I have updated my question with code that can be tested.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Path, PathPatch

# D = pd.read_pickle('directory')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

lons = range(0,361)

lats = [-60, -61, -62, -63, -64, -65, -66, -67, -68, -69, -70,
       -71, -72, -73, -74, -75, -76, -77, -78, -79, -80, -81,
       -82, -83, -84, -85, -86, -87, -88, -89, -90]


lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
variable_to_graph = np.random.rand(31,361)

m = Basemap(projection='spstere', boundinglat=-60, lon_0=180, resolution='l')
m.drawcoastlines(color='k') # shows Antarctica

x,y = m(lon, lat)
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, variable_to_graph, cmap='viridis', vmin=-400, vmax=-0)

# Getting the limits of the map:
x0,x1 = ax.get_xlim()
y0,y1 = ax.get_ylim()
map_edges = np.array([[x0,y0], [x1,y0], [x1,y1], [x0,y1]])

# Getting all polygons used to draw the coastlines of the map
polys = [p.boundary for p in m.landpolygons]

# Combining with map edges.
polys = [map_edges]+polys[:]

# Creating a PathPatch.
codes = [
    [Path.MOVETO] + [Path.LINETO for p in p[1:]]
    for p in polys
]

polys_lin = [v for p in polys for v in p]
codes_lin = [c for cs in codes for c in cs]
path = Path(polys_lin, codes_lin)
patch = PathPatch(path,facecolor='white', lw=0)

# Masking the data:
ax.add_patch(patch)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Basemap was essentially discontinued about 3 years ago... Have you tried using [`cartopy`](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/gallery.html)? I'll take a look when I get a chance, but if you post again, try to include data (or fake data) so people can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I've realised there is a problem with the m.landpolygons command. The length of the list I get is 0, where as in the Greenland example it is 73. So basically m.landpolygons doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: I have now produced a reproducible example. Thanks!