# Fill oceans in high resolution to hide low resolution contours in basemap

Tags: python, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

When plotting low-resolution contours over a high-resolution coastline I get the following result

[image]

I would like to fill the area outside of the coastlines (caused by the low resolution of the underlining filled contour plot) with the ocean color at high resolution.

I tried to use the land-sea mask option without coloring the land

```py
m.drawlsmask(land_color=(0, 0, 0, 0), ocean_color='#2081C3',
resolution='h', lakes=True, zorder=2, grid=1.25)
```

but the 1.25 resolution is not enough for this level of detail (see second image)

[image]

Unfortunately there is no builtin method that fills the ocean (and lakes) with the same resolution used for the coastlines ('h' in my case). As a workaround is there any way to fill the area "outside" of the coastline using the original resolution?

I could use a high resolution land-sea mask in `drawlsmask` but that's a waste of resource since basemap already has indirectly that information with the polygons given by the coastlines.

General notes:

1. It looks like other questions on Stack Overflow suggest to use the builtin land sea mask of basemap. I can't because it is too low resolution at this zoom level.
2. Unfortunately I cannot use Cartopy. I already built my entire pipeline on Cartopy but it is way too slow for what I have to do.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out around code that you are writing. Your question, instead, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Can someone point me towards a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Not really true, but anyway I'm posting my solution as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the solution posted in [Fill oceans in basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620803/fill-oceans-in-basemap) adapted to my needs. Note that, in order to retain the lakes, I had to do multiple passes of `fillcontinents`, so that's how I did

```py
# extents contain the projection extents as [lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2]
m = Basemap(projection='merc',
                llcrnrlat=extents[2],
                urcrnrlat=extents[3],
                llcrnrlon=extents[0],
                urcrnrlon=extents[1],
                lat_ts=20,
                resolution='h')

m.fillcontinents(color='#c5c5c5', lake_color='#acddfe', zorder=1)
# Fill again the lakes over the contour plot
m.fillcontinents(color=(0, 0, 0, 0), lake_color='#acddfe', zorder=3)

ax = plt.gca()

# Workaround to add high resolution oceans 
x0,x1 = ax.get_xlim()
y0,y1 = ax.get_ylim()
map_edges = np.array([[x0,y0],[x1,y0],[x1,y1],[x0,y1]])

# getting all polygons used to draw the coastlines of the map
polys = [p.boundary for p in m.landpolygons]
polys = [map_edges]+polys[:]

codes = [
   [Path.MOVETO] + [Path.LINETO for p in p[1:]]
     for p in polys
  ]

polys_lin = [v for p in polys for v in p] 
codes_lin = [c for cs in codes for c in cs]
path = Path(polys_lin, codes_lin)
patch = PathPatch(path, facecolor='#acddfe', lw=0, zorder=2)

ax.add_patch(patch)

m.drawcountries(linewidth=0.6)
m.readshapefile(f'{SHAPEFILES_DIR}/ITA_adm_shp/ITA_adm2',
                        'ITA_adm2', linewidth=0.1, color='gray', zorder=5)
```

which gives something like this

[image]

Not perfect (because the shapefile which defines the coastline has a different resolution), but definitely better than before.