# How to prevent scatterplot from getting outside of a shapefile map?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am plotting data on a map using Basemap but the circles get outside of the boundary set by the shapefile country outline. I would like to prevent that. I am not really concerned with circles that have their centres outside of the outline because I do not have such in my data but I do want to know how to get rid of the parts of the circles that are outside of the boundaries even though the centre is inside.

Code to reproduce the problem along with the figure:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_color_map():
    color_map = {}
    i = 0
    kick = 255
    for x in range(1,10):
        color_map[x] = ((kick-10*x)/kick,(10*x)/kick,0,0.1*x)
    color_map[10] = (1, 0, 0, 1)
    return color_map

lat = np.linspace(40,48,100)
lon = np.linspace(-100,-90,100)
count = pd.Series(np.logspace(0,1, 100,dtype=int))
color_map = get_color_map()
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-119,llcrnrlat=22,urcrnrlon=-64,urcrnrlat=49,
            projection='lcc',lat_1=33,lat_2=45,lon_0=-95, resolution='c')
# shapefile can be downloaded from
# http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2017/shp/cb_2017_us_nation_20m.zip
shp_info = m.readshapefile('cb_2017_us_nation_20m/cb_2017_us_nation_20m','outline',drawbounds=True,
                           linewidth=0.5,color='black', zorder=2)
lons, lats = m(lon, lat)
sc = m.scatter(lons, lats, c=count.map(color_map), marker = 'o', zorder=1)
plt.savefig('fig1.pdf',dpi=1200)
```

[image: Parts of circles causing the problem]

Comment: You may fill the outside of your shape with white color and lay it on top to hide the overlapping scatters.

Comment: How can you do that?

Comment: I have no idea (yet). If you want me to find out, you may provide a [mcve] that I can run and test with.

Comment: You can use the code above to check that. The link for the shapefile is included.

Comment: There is an error `NameError: name 'color_map' is not defined`. Please make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry. I did not notice that. I've corrected the omission and run the code. It should work now.

Comment: I don't want to plagiarise and you still haven't really given a proper MCVE (missing map data; you should use some example instead), but I'm pretty sure [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48626078/5067311) to an ocean-filling problem can be applied to yours, but instead of land you should loop over the polygons of your country.